# Print letters in lower triangle in C

Tags: c, loops

I spent hours in printing a lower triangle in C. However, I just cannot figure out how to solve this same question with array.

Below is one of the solution I found on net:

```
int main(void)
{
    char ch='A';
    int i,j;
    for(i=1;i<7;i++)               
        {
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)            
            printf("%c",ch++);      
        printf("\n");
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Below is how I try to do the same thing:

```
#define SIZE 8
int main(void){
  char Alphabet[SIZE];
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = 'A'; i < SIZE, j < 'A' + SIZE; i++, j++){
    Alphabet[i] = j;
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++){
      printf("%c", Alphabet[j+i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The result of the code above is :

```
A
BC
CDE
DEFG
EFGHI
FGHIJK
GHIJKLM
HIJKLMNO
```

What should I revise if I want to print as follow:

```
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your `Alphabet` array only has `A` through `H`. The very first thing you need to do is make it larger.

Comment: The condition `i < SIZE, j < 'A' + SIZE` does not do what I think you meant.

Comment: yes, I've revised the size to 26. I wrote i < SIZE, j < 'A' + SIZE used to looping through A ~ Z, though there are  simpler ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a track of elements printed from the `Alphabet` array so far and in the inner loop start printing from next element onward. You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 26

int main(void) {
    char Alphabet[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        Alphabet[i] = 'A' + i;
    }

    // Or simply have the Alphabet array initialized like this
    // char Alphabet[SIZE] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i && k < SIZE; j++) {
            printf("%c", Alphabet[k++]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

---

**EDIT:**

In the comments, a fellow SO contributor said that the above approach is same as the one OP already found as a solution and OP might be looking for approach of calculating the `Alphabet` array index using `i` and `j` only and without use of variable keeping track of array index. Below is the program which does not use any extra variable to keep the track of `Alphabet` array index to print characters in inner loop and calculating the index using `i` and `j`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 26
#define ARRLOC(x) ((x * ((x + 1) / 2)) + ((x % 2 == 0) ? (x / 2) : 0))

int main(void) {
    char Alphabet[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        Alphabet[i] = 'A' + i;
    }

    // Or simply have the Alphabet array declared like this
    // char Alphabet[SIZE] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= i && (ARRLOC(i) + j) < SIZE; j++){
            printf("%c", Alphabet[ARRLOC(i) + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
A
BC
DEF
GHIJ
KLMNO
PQRSTU
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! I do now know what I mistook. I was trying to let j work as k, but I just didn't realize why it failed.

Comment: Jabou, you accepted an answer which drops your approach and basically does the same as the solution you found. That surprises me. I thought you were looking for an answer which sees your approach of caluclating from i and j through. Which is of course possible with a little math on how to add up the numbers from 0...N.

Comment: @Yunnosch Just saw your comment. Added the approach which calculate `Alphabet` array index using only `i` and `j`. Check the edit.

Comment: ... and you got the formula correct. The difference to the one I had in mind is simply explained by mine being wrong.... ;-) (Call it vanity, but I think people responding to my input make good answers....)

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you! I was wondering how to have a variable to count from A to Z, and I learn that the variable is often called "flag" from my C guide book . Also, I was trying to use the 'i' and 'j' to do that.  but as a newbie with C,  I were not aware of that the solution from net and the answer I picked are the same conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a third 'index' variable that keeps track of which letter to output across *both* loops (I've called this `k` in the code below). Also, you need to make your `Alphabet` array bigger (26 seems like a reasonable number); then, if that `k` variable gets past `'Z'`, we can simply loop back to `'A'` using the modulo operator (`%`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 26
int main(void)
{
    char Alphabet[SIZE];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) Alphabet[i] = 'A' + i;

    int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%c", Alphabet[k % 26]); // If past the end, loop back with the "%" operator
            ++k;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or we can make the code a little more 'succinct' (though perhaps less clear) by initializing the `k` variable at the start of the *outer* loop and incrementing at the end of the *inner* loop:

```c
    for (k = i = 0; i <= 7; i++) { // Initialize "k" here ...
        for (j = 0; j <= i; j++, k++) { // .. but increment it here!
            printf("%c", Alphabet[k % 26]); // If past the end, loop back with the "%" operator
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want an 8 by 8 pyramid, you won't have enough characters to do it using the alphabet (requires 36), so I made the alphabet repeat itself (u could also make it go to numeric instead?)

```
#define SIZE 8

int area(int size);

int main(void){
  char Alphabet[area(SIZE)];
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0, j = 'A'; i < area(SIZE); i++, j++){
    if (j > 'Z') j = 'A';
    Alphabet[i] = j;
  }

  int idx=0;
  for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++){
      printf("%c", Alphabet[idx++]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}

int area(int size) {
    if (size==1) return 1;
    return size + area(size - 1);
}
```